# Delete till the previous word

Tags: vim

What's the best, fastest way to delete anything till a previous word (even if it's not on the same line). Example:
(cursor is right before `d` in `dolor`)

```
 Lorem Ipsum
            dolor sit amet
```

I need to delete all spaces until the previous word and position cursor right after `Ipsum`. Result should be:

```
 Lorem Ipsumdolor sit amet
```

with cursor between `m` and `d`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-Jx
```

`-J` to join the second line to line above

`x` to delete the space between the words Ipsum & dolor

Answer (score 4):

You can use `kJ` or `beJ` when the cursor is before letter `d` of `dollar`

```
k move up one line
J Join line below to current line
```

and

```
Lorem Ipsum
           dolor sit amet
```

will become

```
Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> will ALMOST do it.

`d` is the well-known delete operator.

`ge` is the motion to go to the end of the previous word.

But it deletes one character too many. So either add that character back in, or use visual mode to select exactly what you want to delete.

<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>

This will work across any number of lines, or within a single line.

I think if you have only 2 lines you care about though, that the other answers using <kbd>J</kbd> are better.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it can be done in a single cmd.
Here's what I know (**4 keys**):

In escape mode, use `'=='` while you are on the `dolor` line:

```
Lorem Ipsum
dolor sit amet
```

Now, press `up` arrow, to go to the 1st line, and then Press `'A'` , and then a `'del'`

`Lorem Ipsumdolor sit amet`

Comment: `==` doesn't necessarily delete all leading spaces. `d0` would do the trick, but I was wondering if there's a keystroke to combine deleting leading spaces on the same line and trailing spaces(if any) on previous

Comment: Yes, I assumed it would because I assumed you are using a plain text file.

Comment: Instead you can remove all leading white spaces with :%s/^[ \t]*// but I guess it you dont want to delete white spaces from all the line ??

Comment: Yes, d0 is better for individual lines